# Ionic installation

Tags: cmd, npm, ionic2

¡Hi everybody!

So i started having problems with ionic on my computer today.. I've been using/learning ionic for a while, last time i used/run ionic on my laptop was three days ago and it was working fine without any trouble...

But today it is not working anymore... I tried uninstalling/installing again but still can't make it work again...

Can you point me to the right direction? I feel like i'm missing something but i just can't figure it out x.x

[image]

EDIT1:

After a few hours i'm still having troubles...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got solved until i reinstalled ionic and cordova using cmd as administrator.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow , my npm path was not there in PATH environmental Variable

So after adding C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm to my PATH variable my problem solved :-)

Comment: All variables were set and i still had problems... Problem was solved after i restarted my computer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok .That may be problem.So accept answer and close issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check `environment variables` and check `PATH` variable . Check if node, and npm dependencies path is listed or not.